# Java - Split string by regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like below

`[timestamp] [ABC_DEF] this is message.`

In java, I have to split the above string and get only `this is message.`

I tried to split it by getting lastindexof `]` and then substring. But, it is not a proper approach for my use-case cause my message may contain `]` and whole thing goes wrong.

So,  I wanted to do it by using regex.

In regex I want to match `[timestamp] [ABC_DEF]`.Timestamp can be anything but, it has to match [ABC_DEF]. Only then I should get my message.

Any suggestions in writing regex for the same or any if you suggest any other approach is also fine for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Matching of a literal `[ABC_DEF]` does  not seem so difficult, does it? Would you like to give it a try?

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote in your question. Give it a try, we'll help you out if you can't get it done all on your own.

Comment: Re: `lastIndexOf`: why not use `indexOf` (twice)?

Comment: @thomas Haha.. I don't know how to write a regex.

Comment: Try to learn it, it's very useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Comment: try to make use of yourString.indexOf("substring to match")

Comment: @Thomas .. I didn't understand `indexof` (twice). can you be more specific ?

Comment: You wrote in your question that you cannot use `lastIndexOf` because the message might also contain the `]` character. But instead of trying to find the *last* `]` you could simply look for the *second* `]`, since the first `]` comes after the time-stamp, and the second after `ABC_DEF`. So by using `indexOf` once, you can find the end of the time-stamp, and then by using it a second time, you can find the beginning of the message.

Comment: @Thomas... yes, But I think it is good to compare [ABC_DEF] than getting the secondindex of `]` Because `[ABC_DEF]` is constant everytime.

Comment: In that case a single `indexOf` should suffice: with the help of `indexOf("]")` you can find the *beginning* index of `[ABC_DEF]` which allows you to test whether the string *actually* contains `[ABC_DEF]` after that index. If that is the case, you can skip over it, end everything that comes after is your message.

Comment: I am using contains method of String class to check whether line contains `[ABC_DEF]`. if this contains return true then I have to separate message from this line.

Comment: Hint: you can also use `indexOf` instead of `contains` to test whether the line has `[ABC_DEF]` in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128843/discussion-between-deve-and-thomas).

Comment: Are you sure that `[ABC_DEF]` cannot be part of the message, though?

Comment: The characters '[','A','B','C','_','D','E','F',']' can be part of my message. But my line will contain `[ABC_DEF]`. If my line contains `[ABC_DEF]` then I have to get the message.

Comment: @Deve why not just split with a space str.split(" "); and check if the second element equals("[ABC_DEF]")? Better yet, just do a indexOf("[ABC_DEF]") then substring the rest.

Comment: Ok, use `"\\[ABC_DEF]\\s*(.*)"` regex to match and grab the group 1 contents. Or replace: `.replaceFirst(".*\\[ABC_DEF]\\s*","")`

Answer (score 1):

With just `String` methods:

```java
String filter = "[ABC_DEF]";
int filterIndex = line.indexOf(filter);
if (filterIndex >= 0) {
    return line.substring(filterIndex + filter.length()).trim();
}
```

Here, you check whether the string `[ABC_DEF]` is contained in `line` and if so at which position in the string. Then you jump over that occurrence by adding the length of `[ABC_DEF]` to the index at which it was found. The remainder of the line is the message and it is extracted using the `substring` method. Finally, unnecessary whitespace is truncated with `trim()`.

---

With regular expressions:

```java
String filter = "\\[ABC_DEF\\]"; // note the backslashs
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[[^]]*\\]\\s+" + filter + "\\s*(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    return matcher.group(1).trim();
}
```

First, you compile a regular expression that should match the `line`. (When checking multiple lines, the `Pattern` definition should only be done once.) Since `[` and `]` are characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions, we have to escape them with backslashs when including them in the regex. The message part of a line is captures between `(` and `)`, so that - in case the expression matches - we can easily extract the message part using the `group` method. As in the case above, we remove unnecessary whitespace at the beginning and end of the message with `trim()`.